# Does Newtonsoft.Json Serialization Support Year-Only Date Fields?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, iso8601

According to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) json date fields can contain partial data, e.g. `"YYYY"` for year-only or `"YYYY-MM"` for year-month-only.

But, the following code, using [Json.NET deserializer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) that's supposed to support it, throws a format error:

```
class PartialDateContainter
{
    public DateTime MyPartialDate { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void JustCheckJsonDates()
{
    var serializationSettings =
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
            ContractResolver = new ReadOnlyJsonContractResolver(),
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
                new Iso8601TimeSpanConverter(),
                new IsoDateTimeConverter()
            }
        };

    var ser = JsonSerializer.Create(serializationSettings);

    var json = "{ \"MyPartialDate\": \"2005\" }";

    var shus = ser.Deserialize<PartialDateContainter>(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)));

    Assert.True(true);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Year plus month works (e.g. `"2005-05"`), just year-only dates fail to deserialize (e.g. `"2005"`).

Comment: @Nkosi no, it still didn't solve, my problem is year-only date formats.

Comment: Then you will need a custom converter.

Comment: I don't see anything that says year-only partial dates are valid. Can't you just use a string or int instead?

Comment: @Crowcoder, there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years.
And I can, but that's not the question..

Comment: That is part of your question and I still dont see it in the spec. For my own education, specifically what sentence(s) are you referring to?

Comment: @Crowcoder, http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html, https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime. "ISO 8601 also specifies a number of alternative formats for use in applications with special requirements. [...] If only the month or even only the year is of interest: 1995-02 or 1995"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Newtonsoft.Json Serialization Support Year-Only Date Fields?

**Not by default.**

But it is flexible enough that is can be configured to support year only date fields.

Referencing Json.Net documentation here [Serializing Dates in JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm)

> If your dates don't follow the ISO 8601 standard, then the
>   `DateFormatString` setting can be used to customize the format of date
>   strings that are read and written using .NET's [custom date and time
>   format syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

The following simplified example worked

```
[TestClass]
public class JsonNetDateSerializationTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void JustCheckJsonDates() {
        //Arrange
        var settings =
            new JsonSerializerSettings {
                DateFormatString = "yyyy", //<-- for year only dates. all others should parse fine
            };

        var json = "{ \"YearOnly\": \"2017\", \"YearMonth\": \"2017-04\", \"YearMonthDay\": \"2017-04-02\" }";
        var expected = 2017;

        //Act
        var actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PartialDateContainter>(json, settings);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.YearOnly.Year);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.YearMonth.Year);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.YearMonthDay.Year);
    }

    class PartialDateContainter {
        public DateTime YearOnly { get; set; }
        public DateTime YearMonth { get; set; }
        public DateTime YearMonthDay { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: My string **does follow** the ISO 8601 standard, I don't want to force feed it a format string. I want it to be able to parse all ISO 8601 standard strings.

Comment: @Nitzankin Then that is a limitation of the Json.Net framework. Check to see if an issue was already raised for it. If not create one and notify the developer.

Comment: @Nitzankin, Even calling `var dt = DateTime.Parse("2005")` will throw a formatting exception unless a format is provided.

Comment: @Nitzankin check test showing it able to parse all ISO 8601 string including year only.

Comment: Thank you, just want to emphasize that this doesn't seem to follow ISO 8601 as can be seen here: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html, http://w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime. "ISO 8601 also specifies a number of alternative formats for use in applications with special requirements. [...] If only the month or even only the year is of interest: 1995-02 or 1995"

Comment: I know what the wiki says but unless the developer of the code can explain the exact reason their code does not conform to that specification then we are left finding a work around. My assumption is that it was open to interpretation when the developer created the code.