# How to remove time format in Date Field (Json Data)

Tags: c#

As per below link,I have solved my date format problem in Json Data.I would like to know how to remove time format in Date Field.

Form example :-

2020-01-25T00:00:00 --- Time Format

but I need 2020-01-25

[Date Properly not formated in Json File using Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62421867/date-properly-not-formated-in-json-file-using-newtonsoft?noredirect=1#comment110397977_62421867)

Comment: This question is not clear. What is the input, and what is the expected output? Please show example in code rather than plain text if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You always could store Date as string and parse it afterwads. c# DateTime has ToString method and you could do smthn like `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`
and to parse this string to DateTime - `DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Actually I am converting Json Data using Newtonsoft library in C#.Please check my code in above link...

Comment: @KHIT could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168202/does-newtonsoft-json-serialization-support-year-only-date-fields